# a generic builder to create a comparator for arbitrary objects, which can take a arbitrary data member in the object to sort

Tags: c++

I need to write a comparator builder which can generate a comparator for `std:sort`. This builder can deal with any generic objects, and take an arbitrary data member of the object in `std:vector` to sort. so we need to pass in the class data member pointer to `comparator_builder`'s constructor. The usage and the interface of this `comparator_builder` is shown below:

```
vector<T> arr;

sort( arr.begin(), arr.end(), comparator_builder( &T::data_memeber ) );
```

Since we don't know what objects to be sorted is before-hand, we can't know what data member will be in it. We need to also make the class member pointer generic. No idea how to implement it using template.  Is there any C++ expert or genius who can give me some guidance?

### The following is my code. But they can't be complied even.

```
template <typename ObjectType, typename MemberType >
class Comparator {

public:

    Comparator ( ObjectType::data_address ) {

        data_ptr = &data_address
    }


    bool operator()( ObjectType x, ObjectType y ) {

        return x.*data_ptr < y.*data_ptr;

    }

    MemberType ObjectType::* data_ptr;

};



template <typename ObjectType, typename MemberType >
class Comparator_Builder{

    ObjectType::member_address ;

public:

    Comparator_Builder( ObjectType::mem_address ) {

        member_address = mem_address;
    }


    Comparator < ObjectType, MemberType ObjectType::* > operator()() {

        return Comparator < ObjectType, MemberType ObjectType::* >( member_address );

    }


};
```

Comment: Hand a read about `std::tie` and look at the examples https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie

Comment: The syntax is more verbose than it has to be, but otherwise this is a great exercise. We're not a code writing service though. I suggest trying to do it yourself, then ask us if you hit a specific problem. Show your code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thanks for your reminder. I would like to share my codes. but too many errors. I am thinking how to correct it. Not familiar with class member pointer usages..

Comment: Code with errors is ok. Also add the errors.

Comment: understood, HolyBlackCat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already most of the way there with your comparator class:

```
template <typename ObjectType, typename MemberType>
class MemberComparator {
 public:
  using MemberPtr = MemberType ObjectType::*;
  explicit MemberComparator(MemberPtr ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {}

  bool operator()(const ObjectType& x, const ObjectType& y) const {
    return x.*m_ptr < y.*m_ptr;
  }

 private:
  MemberPtr m_ptr;
};
```

Just a few syntax fixes and that's all you need. Constructor template argument deduction also makes this really easy to use in C++17:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), MemberComparator(&T::data_member));
```

If you don't have C++17 you either have to manually specify the template parameters or you can create a template function to do the deduction:

```
template <typename ObjectType, typename MemberType>
auto GetComparator(MemberType ObjectType::*ptr) {
  return MemberComparator<ObjectType, MemberType>(ptr);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), GetComparator(&T::data_member));
```

From the comments:

> is it possible that we make argument passed into GetComparator() more generic? so that we can also pass in getter function, which is class function pointer, like this std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), GetComparator(&T:: get_data_member) );?

Yes, we could certainly add implementations for member functions, though you'll start to run into problems if those getters are overloaded. This can be made more generic, however:

```
template <typename F>
auto GetComparator(F&& func) {
  return [f = std::forward<F>(func)](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs) {
    return f(lhs) < f(rhs);
  };
}
```

Now we can do this:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto &value) { return value.get_data_member(); });
```

This can likewise replace the member pointer comparator we have above by just doing e.g.:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto &value) { return value.data_member; });
```

If you like the member pointer syntax we can add overloads for that and even replace the `MemberComparator` class entirely:

```
template <typename ObjectType, typename MemberType>
auto GetComparator(MemberType ObjectType::*ptr) {
  return [ptr](const ObjectType& lhs, const ObjectType& rhs) {
    return lhs.*ptr < rhs.*ptr;
  };
}

template <typename ObjectType, typename MemberType>
auto GetComparator(MemberType (ObjectType::*ptr)()) {
  return [ptr](ObjectType& lhs, ObjectType& rhs) {
    return (lhs.*ptr)() < (rhs.*ptr)();
  };
}

template <typename ObjectType, typename MemberType>
auto GetComparator(MemberType (ObjectType::*ptr)() const) {
  return [ptr](const ObjectType& lhs, const ObjectType& rhs) {
    return (lhs.*ptr)() < (rhs.*ptr)();
  };
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate it, Kyle!!! I am not familiar with template and class member pointer programming. Believe it or not, last night I looked at code carefully and tried different ways, and luckily I got the same codes working out and the same as yours!

Comment: Kyle, is it possible that we make argument  passed into GetComparator() more generic? so that we can also pass in getter function, which is class function pointer,  like this std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), GetComparator(&T:: get_data_member) );?

Comment: @ToughRabbit Yes, in fact, it's certainly possible to make this more generic, I'll edit the answer with a more generic approach.

Comment: thanks a lot. I spent some time learning about some c++14 and c++17. I tried to add this line "std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto &value) { return value.data_member; });" to my code. but it can't compile. we need to call GetComparator(F&& func) first?

Comment: the compiler error message is: 

/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:215:11: error: no match for call to ‘(main()::<lambda(const auto:1&)>) (Person&, Person&)’
  215 |  { return bool(_M_comp(__val, *__it)); }